# Shared vtables between classes of same name: call to virtual method crashes when casting to base type

Tags: c++

Check below for UPDATE, I could reproduce and need help.

I have a strange crash where some method works fine everywhere except in 1 place. Here's the code:

```
struct base
{
    virtual wchar_t* get() = 0; // can be { return NULL; } doesn't matter
};

struct derived: public base
{
    virtual wchar_t* get() { return SomeData(); }
};

struct container 
{
    derived data;
};

// this is approx. how it is used in real program
void output(const base& data) 
{ 
     data.get(); 
}

smart_ptr<container> item = GetItSomehow();
derived &v1 = item->data;
v1.get(); // works OK
//base &v2 = (base&)derived; // the old line, to understand old comments in the question
base &v2 = v1; // or base* v2 doesn't matter
v2.get(); // segmentation fault without going into method at all
```

Now, as I said, I call item->data.get() in many places on different objects and it works... always. Except for 1 place. But there it doesn't work **only** if casted to base class (*output* is an example why it is needed).

Now, the question is - **HOW** and **WHY** this can happen? I'd suspect pure virtual call but I don't call virtual method in the constructor. I don't see how the calls are different. I would suspect base method is abstract but it is same if I add a body to it.

I cannot provide a small example to test because, as I said, it works always, except for 1 place. If I knew why it doesn't work there, I wouldn't need the test sample because that would already be the answer...

P.S. The environment is Ubuntu 11.10 x64 but the program is compiled for 32 bit using gcc 4.5.2 custom build.

P.P.S. Another clue, not sure if related...

```
warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `derived::get' value
warning:   found `SomeOtherDerivedFromBaseClass::SomeOtherCrazyFunction' instead
```

in the real program

UPDATE: Any chance this can happen because of gcc linking vtable to a wrong class with same name but inside different shared library? The "derived" class in real app actually defined in several shared libraries, and worse, there's another similar class with same name but different interface. What's strange is that without casting to base class it works.

I am especially interested in gcc/linking/vtables details here.

Here's how I seem to reproduce:

```
// --------- mod1.h
class base
{
public:
   virtual void test(int i); // add method to make vtables different with mod2
   virtual const char* data();
};

class test: public base
{
public:
   virtual const char* data();
};


// --------- mod2.h
class base
{
public:
   virtual const char* data();
};

class test: public base
{
public:
   virtual const char* data();
};

// --------- mod2.cpp
#include "mod2.h"
const char* base::data() { return "base2"; }
const char* test::data() { return "test2"; }

// --------- modtest.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
// !!!!!!!!! notice that we include mod1
#include "mod1.h"

int main()
{
   test t;
   base& b = t;
   printf("%s\n", t.data());
   printf("%s\n", b.data());
   return 0;
}

// --------- how to compile and run
g++ -c mod2.cpp && g++ mod2.o modtest.cpp  && ./a.out

// --------- output from the program
queen3@pro-home:~$ ./a.out 
test2
Segmentation fault
```

In the modtest above, if we include "mod2.h" instead of "mod1.h", we get normal "test2\ntest2" output without segfault.

The question is - what is the exact mechanism for this? How to detect and prevent? I knew that static data in gcc will be linked to single memory entry, but vtables...

Comment: Why the cast?  Seems unnecessary and dangerous.  You may accidentally cast to the wrong thing.

Comment: Upcasting doesn't need cast, neither is cast needed when dealing with references.

Comment: btw:  I'm assuming you meant base &v2 = (base&)v1;

Comment: Remove the cast -- not only is it a C-style cast (yuck), but also because it's unnecessary and counter-productive.

Comment: @VaughnCato: That may be the bug.

Comment: Right, sorry, (base&)v1. As for why the cast, because it is used to pass different objects to output(), i.e. function that accepts different objects. Thus, I cannot remove the cast. The cast in code is just to show the exact point where it crashes, not because I cast in code. It is casted automatically when output(base&) or SomeObjectCtor(base&) is called.

Comment: How do you know it wouldn't fail if you didn't pass the object as as a reference to the base?  Have you tried creating an identical version of the function that takes a derived reference and calling that instead?

Comment: I do call v1.get() and it is a call on derived reference, isn't it? Also, I _do_ pass it as reference to the base to the output() function, similar function is where the call fails in the real program.

Comment: Your example program doesn't fail, so we can't really use that as an example.  I'm talking about changing your real code.  You are saying that your real program crashes when you cast to the base (btw: this is a conversion not a cast), so I was suggesting making a duplicate version of your function that takes a derived reference instead.  If it still crashes, then you know it has nothing to do with the conversion.

Comment: Hm, OK, will try. But I *do* try derived reference call in the real program (i.e. v1.get() as in example), just right in code, not as passing to a duplicate version of output(). I wonder if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit in response to update:
In your updated code where you use `mod1` and `mod2` header you're violating the One Definition Rule for classes (even by appearing in shared libraries). It basically states that in your entire program you must have only one definition of a class (`base` in this case) although the same definition can appear in multiple source files. If you have more than one definition then all bets are off and you get undefined behavior. In this case, the undefined behavior happens to be a crash. The fix is of course to not have multiple versions of the same class in the same program. This is usually accomplished by defining each class in a single header (or implementation for non-API/impl classes) and including that header where the class definition is needed.

Original answer:
If it works everywhere except one place it sounds like the object isn't valid in that one place (working as derived pointer but not as base sounds a lot like you entered the realm of undefined behavior). Either it's corrupted memory, a deleted object pointer, or something else. Your best bet is if you can run valgrind on it.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but I can't understand why in this case v1.get() works fine in 100% cases? As well as other calls like item->GetOtherData().

Comment: But thanks for the valgrind tip. Should put it into my toolbox from now on.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is in your question: *"Shared vtables between classes of same name ..."*.

You have a compiled a single binary from two cpp files, but each cpp file included a different header file and in particular a different definition of `struct base`. In C++, you can't have two classes with the same name. If the same name is used, then they are the same class and you must be consistent. (The obvious exception is to put them in two different namespaces.)

(Everything here is compiler-specific. But this is probably a typical approach across most compilers.)

First, let's understand non-virtual methods. When you execute such a method on an object:

```
b.foo(3);
```

the code is basically rewritten as follows as if it were a conventional free function:

```
foo_(b,3);
```

with the method implemented as follows:

```
void foo_(base * this, int i) {
    ...
}
```

i.e. the `this` pointer is 'secretly' passed as the first parameter to the function.

But things aren't so simple with `virtual` methods. There will be two different free functions that implement `get`. We'll call one of these `get_base` and the other `get_derived`. (Never mind that you actually have a pure virtual method (`=0`), it doesn't really change the story.)

The question is, how is the correct `get` selected at runtime for execution? Well, for each class that has at least one virtual method, the compiler builds a vtable. The vtable for a given class lists all the virtual methods in that class. For example

```
struct vtable_for_base_t {
    wchar_t* (*get_function_pointer)(base *); // initialized to get_base    
};
vtable_for_base_t vtable_for_base;
vtable_for_base.get_function_pointer = &get_base;

vtable_for_????_t vtable_for_derived;
vtable_for_derived.get_function_pointer = &get_derived;
```

The type of the function pointer is a function which takes one parameter (a `base*`, which will become `this`) and which returns `wchar_t*`.

The two classes, `base` and `derived` actually include pointers to these vtables under the hood.

```
struct base {
    vtable_for_base_t * vtable;
    .... other members of base
};

struct derived {
    vtable_for_????_t * vtable;
    .... other members of derived
};
```

Whenever a `base` object is constructed, the `vtable` pointer is initialized to point to the vtable for `base`. Whenever a `derived` object is constructed, it points to the vtable for `derived` instead. Now, whenever the compiler sees `b.get()` it will change this to the following

```
(b.vtable->get_function_pointer)(&b);
```

It looks up the vtable pointed to by the b object to get a function pointer to the correct version of `get` to use. And then it passes `b` to that function, in order to ensure that it has a correct `this` pointer.

In summary, each object has a (hidden) member that knows the correct version of the `virtual` functions. In this case, the compiler assumes that the *first* entry in the vtable for base, *and also the vtable for any type derived from base*, will be the `get` method.

***When constructing vtables for derived classes, the first entries will correspond to the methods which were in the base class. And they will be in the same order as they were in the base. Any new virtual methods in the derived class will be listed later.***

If you had two virtual methods, `foo` and `bar`, in `base`, then these will be the first two entries in the vtable for `base`, and the corresponding versions for derived will also take up the first two slots in the vtable for `derived`.

Now, to understand why you're getting a segfault. In `mod2.h`, a vtable for base is created where `data` is the first (and only) entry. Therefore, any code that includes `mod2.h` and which attempts to execute `b.data()` will execute the *first* entry in the vtable. But that's not relevant when `modtest.cpp` is being compiled, because it includes `mod1.h` instead.

`modtest.cpp` includes `mod1.h`. As a result, it sees a `base` class that has two methods, where `data` is the *second* method listed in the vtable. Therefore, any attempt to execute `b.data` will actually become:

```
(b.vtable.SECOND_ENTRY)(&b);
```

because it assumes that the second entry will be the `data()` entry.

It will attempt to get the second entry from the vtable, but the real vtable (created in `mod2.h`) has only one entry! Therefore it's trying to access invalid memory and everything fails.

In short, consider defining these two structs in two different header files in C:

```
 // in one file
 struct A {
     int i;
     char c[500];
 }

 // in another file
 struct A {
     char c[500];
     int i;
 }
```

Nobody would expect this to work. The program would often be accessing the wrong memory. Therefore, you shouldn't mess with vtables.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to cast explicitly when treating derived class as a parent class:

```
#include <iostream> 

struct A {
    virtual void get() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : public A {
    virtual void get() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    B b;
    A & a = b;
    a.get();
    return 0;
}
```

What's more explicit cast in this case might hide bugs. By casting you tell compiler that you are aware of what you are doing and it will not stop, or in many cases not even warn you, that you are doing something that will fail.

If it doesn't compile without the cast it means there is an error in the code (and in most cases compiler gives you the cause in the error message).

Comment: OK this is purely syntax change, it doesn't solve the crash at all. Surely the reason for the crash is not the cast (the cast itself is automatic in output() and so is done everywhere).

Comment: Create a small test case that shows the problem and post it [here](http://ideone.com). Without that there is not much we can do as we are missing the code that is probably the cause.

Comment: As I said in the question, I **cannot** create test case because the problem is not reproducible there. Not that I did not try - I did, it works in test case and in all places of the program (there're many of them). Everywhere, except in 1 place. The question is, **how** this can happen, only in 1 place, what can be wrong.

Comment: What is actually `smart_ptr` in your code? This would be the first thing I would check. Maybe object was deleted, maybe pointer was changed to some invalid address. Those things lead to "random" crashes.

Comment: Well, then why it is called without problem as v1.get()? This is what I can't understand. Also, other calls (in real program) on this object works fine, too. But I tried to check if there's something wrong with the Ptr, it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Are you sure that it is "without problem"? In many cases I saw with calls to methods on invalid pointers they did not cause segfault. And undefined mean undefined. It break, it can work but give you rubbish or it can give results which seem valid at first.

Comment: Well, I called 5 methods and accessed 3 other container objects like derived, I traced it's creation, it all looks good. Now, is there a way to check that vptrs are OK or object is OK?

Answer (score 3):

In your second example you are violating the [one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

To Quote from Wikipedia:

1. In any translation unit, a template, type, function, or object can have no more than one definition. Some of these can have any number of declarations. A definition provides an instance.
2. In the entire program, an object or non-inline function cannot have more than one definition; if an object or function is used, it must have exactly one definition. You can declare an object or function that is never used, in which case you don't have to provide a definition. In no event can there be more than one definition.
3. Some things, like types, templates, and extern inline functions, can be defined in more than one translation unit. For a given entity, each definition must be the same. Non-extern objects and functions in different translation units are different entities, even if their names and types are the same.

You are violating part 2 of the rule. Both `base` as well as `test` are declared multiple times and conflicting in `mod1.hh` and `mod2.hh`, hence your program is invalid and invokes undefined behavior. Hence you sometimes experience crashes and sometimes you done. Your program is invalid nevertheless. The compiler does not have to warn you, because both definitions appear in different translation units and the standard does not require it to check for consistency accross compilation units in this case.

Preventing this kind of problem is quite easy. This is what namespaces were invented for. Try to separate your classes in a specific namespace and ODR will not be a problem anymore.

Detecting this kind of thing is a bit harder. One thing you can try is a [unity-build](http://buffered.io/posts/the-magic-of-unity-builds/). This looks really scary at first sight, but actually helps in solving a lot of problems with this kind of thing. As a sideeffect a unity-build will also speed up compilation time while you are developing. The link above gives instructions for using a unity-build in Visual Studio, but it is actually quite simple to add to makefiles as well (including the automatic generation of the necessary header).

Comment: The project uses cmake so I think it is possible to implement UB without too much pain. Not sure if I do but, build time is already too big and... anyway, I'd give +100 just for the link, a really neat idea. I can see how it will detect duplicated definition problems, too. But not in all cases (if "most complete" .h is included first, no error will be given). And wikipedia article is helpful (since I agree with it and customers do not).

Comment: Also http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility (in the C++ exceptions section) tells few more bad things about breaking ODR. http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html referenced from there is also useful to read, and also mentions ODR. The more I read the more I think I should convince customers to fix the violation of that.

Comment: @queen3: Testing a fast simulated unity-build on ideone.com (http://ideone.com/k13AV) gives me a `error: redefinition of ‘class base’` so this does not matter on the order of the includes at all. Unless somebody messed up really bad and also has duplicate `#defines` for the header-guards. In this case anthing could happen during any build, since one would never know what gets included when.

Comment: @queen3: Actually now that I think about it, there is one case where a unity-build will fail: Anonymous namespaces. In this case you can safely have a seemingly same name in multiple compilation units without trouble. However these namespaces are only separated when used in different compilation units and a unity-build might break them.

Comment: Well, actually it _is_ possible that somebody messed it up and has duplicated #defines. Since, that's really just the same .h file, they just decided that for one module they don't need some stuff in the derived class. But if it uses #pragma once, UB will detect. And no there're no anonymous namespaces. Also, thanks for one more nice ideone.com link, always wanted something like this after jsfiddle.

Comment: OK, you were the first to mention ODR, which led me to lots of useful investigations, so here are the points.

Answer (score 1):

```
base &v2 = (base&)derived; // or base* v2, doesn't matter
```

should read

```
base &v2 = v1;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I changed the line. Not that it solves the problem, though.

Comment: @queen3: Even Sherlock Holmes could figure this out now: The problem isn't in the code you posted :-)

Comment: Then check where your item is from. I basically copy-and-pasted your code and removed all the the pseudo-code and it builds and executes without any problems. Oh and by the way, struct base **should** really have a virtual destructor!

Comment: Yes, the problem is not in the code, but I provide code so that someone could look at it and have a clue or an idea why/what can be wrong. If I could create a test case I'd solve this myself easily, but whatever I do it "builds and executes without any problems". As for virtual destructor, interesting clue... I'll check. But the base struct is really base - there's only pure method defined and that's all, no data, I don't think this can be the reason. But I'll think about it, good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here isn't a violation of the one definition rule. In fact, the one definition rule is ONE problem, but it can be solved by using this method.

A dynamic cast will fix'er'up.

```
test t;
// Using a pointer to make the cast a little more obvious
base *b = dynamic_cast<base *>(&t);
```

That's straight out of the C++ documentation website at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/. It'll return a NULL pointer or throw an exception on failure, depending. Either way, you'll catch the error at run-time.

<del>Although dynamic_casts are technically better practice, it is possible to use a static_cast also.</del> UPDATE: you wanted to know how to catch it at run-time, and a static_cast probably won't catch it at compile time either, sorry.

Nextly, to avoid problems like this in the future, use explicit namespaces. There's really no reason ever to not use them. Even your main program can use one, even if it's long, by aliasing it.

I'll rip an example from [IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/creating_a_namespace_alias.htm) because they're schmucks:

```
namespace INTERNATIONAL_BUSINESS_MACHINES {
  void f();
}

namespace IBM = INTERNATIONAL_BUSINESS_MACHINES;
```

If your libraries aren't using namespaces then they are poor libraries and should be deleted, then the media they were on should be dipped in a vat of acid, and whatever tubes you downloaded them through should get a triple dose of Draino. Though of course we often are stuck using code that leaves things to be desired...

Comment: Oh, in some cases, it is possible to add namespaces around library include files... namespace foo { #include "library.hh"; #include "library2.hh" } This only works in some cases, but can help if you're stuck with ones using the same names and no namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is - what is the exact mechanism for this?

See the other answers about ODR.

> How to detect and prevent?

Create a massive translation for your libraries, and include every dependency in it.

Make sure you're using proper scoping and visibility.  If it's image-private, that's one case (anon or reserved image namespaces). Otherwise, it should be public and visible to clients via inclusion. Including everything in one TU and using well defined conventions for scoping and visibility will catch *many* of the errors.

The linker can also kick in in some cases. In fact, exporting your virtual defs is a great idea for many reasons -- the linker would have spotted this issue.

> I knew that static data in gcc will be linked to single memory entry, but vtables...

may be duplicated if virtuals definitions are visible. That is, your entire rtti-info and vtable may be exported per TU which can cause serious bloat and add quite a bit to compile and link times.